# Pusher_Channels_Flutter cannot connect private_channel in IOS

Tags: flutter

In the pusher_client_flutter package, the onAuthorize function does not work in the private channel about flutter ios.I think the onAuthorize function doesn't work because I don't get the socket ID.f you know why, could you please let me know?`